# How to combine two different list into one list in Android

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a list of cities I like to display from a json file.  I also have to two items, "New Cities", "Favourite Cities". And also two image in front of "New Cities" and "Favourite Cities".

My question is how to combine the two different lists together in an activity.  Thanks.

```
// Load from file "cities.json" first time
if (mAdapter == null) {
    List<City> cities = null;
    try {
        cities = loadCities();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // This is the GridView adapter
    ListAdapter = new CityAdapter(this);
    ListAdapter.setData(cities);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to concatenate the lists? And is it related to Realm database?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes.  I would like to do it in realm database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to concatenate two lists, here's how you an do it

```
List<City> cities = loadCities();
cities.addAll(loadFavoriteCities);
ListAdapter.setData(cities);
```

If you want to display two different lists in one activity one near by another, using of two `ListView` or `RecyclerView` is the solution;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list1"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```